# For a TCP server when does poll let you know when the socket is ready?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, polling

Does poll give a POLLIN revent when the first TCP segment arrives or after the entire TCP message arrives? If the former is it possible that the first segment of a TCP message is sent, but not the complete message? How would the server handle that read so it won't block forever?

Edit: I've realized the solution to my problem if I wanted to persist with a TCP socket. I might try a SCTP socket instead. Seems to be more in line with how I want it to work.

Comment: TCP has no "messages". If peer need to read some known amount of data, it can `recv()` by chunks to buffer in a loop until all needed size is received.

Comment: I've done some reading and it seems like this is a question of the innter workings of TCP. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the OS (Linux in this case) will buffer the TCP messages until the TCP push flag (AKA, all segments have been sent) is set, then the OS will return a POLLIN revent. Is that correct?

Comment: POLLIN is returned when read from descriptor (in your case from socket) would not block. That's all. `recv()` will return as much data as already buffered (but not more than requested, of course).

Comment: POLLIN is set when there is at least one byte of incoming TCP data available for `recv()` to return to you.  No guarantees are made (or expected) about how many bytes will be available -- in particular, the number of bytes available to read will likely be different than the number of bytes the sender previously passed to `send()`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If the read() doesn't get all the bytes I am expecting does that thread have to wait in a loop until all the bytes that I am expecting arrive? What if it takes a minute for the rest of the bytes to arrive?

Comment: You can store the bytes you did receive in a buffer and then call poll() again; repeat until you have enough bytes in your buffer to do something useful with them.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is stream, not messages. So, pollin can be happened after any amount of data received

Comment: So how does the server handle only part of the data being sent? How do you stop the read() from blocking or continuing without all the data server side?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can receive e.g. 1000 bytes from socket in conjunction with `poll()`:

```c
char buffer[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
char *p = buffer;
size_t bytes_left = 1000;   // Must be less or equal to MAX_MSG_SIZE

for (;;)
{
    int ret = poll(fds, num_fds, timeout);

    if (ret == -1) {
        // Handle poll() errors here
        // ...
        break;
    }
    if (ret == 0) {
        // Handle timeout here
        // ...
        continue;
    }

    if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)    // Assume socket descriptor is in fds[0].fd
    {
        ssize_t len = recv(fds[0].fd, p, bytes_left, 0);

        if (len == -1) {
            // Handle recv() errors here
            // ...
        }

        bytes_left -= len;
        p += len;

        if (bytes_left == 0) {
            // Do something with 1000 bytes in buffer
            // ...

            // Read next "message", e.g. 500 bytes
            bytes_left = 500;
            p = buffer;
        }
    }

    // Handle other fds events
    // ...
}
```